# How to apply CSS to all input elements except for input within li of certain class

Tags: html, css

```css
input.not(li.tagit-new >input) {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<ul id="tagAdministrator" style="width: 505px" class="tagit ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
  <li class="tagit-new" style="box-shadow: none;">
    <input type="text" class="ui-widget-content ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off">//css should not be applied to this
  </li>
</ul>

<input type="text" class="ui-widget-content ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off"> //css should be applied to this
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `:not()` pseudo can only accept [simple selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#simple-selectors-dfn) and requires a colon!

```css
input {background: grey;}
li.tagit-new input {background: purple;}
```

```html
<ul id="tagAdministrator" style="width: 505px" class="tagit ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
  <li class="tagit-new" style="box-shadow: none;">
    <input type="text" class="ui-widget-content ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off">//css should not be applied to this
  </li>
</ul>

<input type="text" class="ui-widget-content ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off"> //css should be applied to this
```

Answer (score 1):

I would make two different styles:

```
input {
    background-color:lightgrey;
}
li > input {
    background-color:white;
}
```

Or give the "outside of li"-inputs a class.

Answer (score 1):

If need default background color you can use background-color:inherit;

```
 input {background-color:lightgrey;}
 li.tagit-new > input{background-color:inherit;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/276jvy2f/